# Java: How do I compare a string taken from user to a array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
 public String bookName() {
        String[] books = {"Absolute Java", "JAVA: How to Program",
                "Computing Concepts with JAVA 8 Essentials", "Java Software Solutions",
                "Java Program Design"};

        System.out.println("Enter the title to search for: ");
        String userSelection = scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(books).contains(userSelection)) {
                System.out.println(books[i]);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing");
            }
        }
        return bookName();
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing two approaches here. You should do either 1) loop over the *array* and check for equality of the current array element and the `String`s via `equals()` or 2) check if the `String` is contained in the *list* via `contains()`. Currently you mix these approaches, so you don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already iterating through the Array, you can simply compare.  Try setting a boolean value so that you are not printing for every iteration.

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if (books[i].equals(userSelection)) {
            System.out.println(books[i]);
            found = true;
            break;
        } 
 }

 if (!found) {
    System.out.println("nothing");
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(books[i]);` refers to an out-of-scope variable `i`.

Comment: @saka1029 - Noob mistake ;-)  Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `indexOf` like this.

```
String[] books = {"Absolute Java", "JAVA: How to Program",
    "Computing Concepts with JAVA 8 Essentials", "Java Software Solutions",
    "Java Program Design"};
List<String> bookList = Arrays.asList(books);
System.out.println("Enter the title to search for: ");
String userSelection = scanner.nextLine();
int i = bookList.indexOf(userSelection);
if (i >= 0)
    System.out.println(books[i]);
else
    System.out.println("nothing");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Streams:

```
    public String bookName() {

        System.out.println("Enter the title to search for: ");

        String userSelection = scanner.nextLine();

        return Stream.of(
                "Absolute Java",
                "JAVA: How to Program",
                "Computing Concepts with JAVA 8 Essentials",
                "Java Software Solutions",
                "Java Program Design")
        /* Either: */ .filter(bookName -> 0 == bookName.compareToIgnoreCase(userSelection))
        /* ....or: */ .filter(bookName -> bookName.toLowerCase().contains(userSelection.toLowerCase()))
        .limit(1)
        .peek(bookName -> System.out.println(bookName))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            System.out.println("nothing");
            return null;
        });
    }
```